# Syntax for extract in mysql

Tags: mysql, datetime

Is this the correct use of 'extract' in mysql?

```
select count(user_id) from users where registration_date >= extract(week from now());
```

this query is to get the count of registrations in the current week

Tried to replace postgreSQL's 'date_trunc' with 'extract'

Comment: What are you defining as "week" here?  Past 7 days, current calendar week (according to some definition), something else?

Comment: current calendar week

Comment: Please show your exact postgres query?  It's not clear how you are using date_trunc.  Or describe exactly what you want the outcome to be.  Or both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you ask about synthactical correctness, then the answer is **YES**.

Function usage `extract(week from now())` completely matches the pattern described in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_extract).

---

If you are interested in logic correctness, then the answer is **NO**.

You use `where registration_date >= extract(week from now())`. How does this condition is processed?

Firstly the function is evaluated. The function output is numeric WEEK value for specified DATETIME value, and its datatype is BIGINT.

Then the comparing is performed. One of the operands is some DATE datatype, another one is function output (not constant) of BIGINT. So the comparing context is set to numeric according to [Type Conversion in Expression Evaluation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/type-conversion.html), the arguments are compared as floating-point (double-precision) numbers. `registration_date` is converted to something similar to `20221230` which is obviously greater than the function output which is `52`. So **ALL rows** which does not store NULL in the column matches the condition.

---

The most simple and at the same time logically correct condition is

```
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(registration_date, '%Y%u') >= DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE, '%Y%u')
```

The pattern may be, of course, adjusted if the "week" term does not match the description "Monday is the first day of the week ([WEEK() mode 1](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week))". But this condition is not [SARGable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable). Apply it if the index by `registration_date` column is not present in the table.

---

So I'd recommend to use the next condition (for week mode 1):

```
WHERE registration_date >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL (DAYOFWEEK(CURRENT_DATE) + 5) MOD 7 DAY
```

Of course it is more complex - but it is [SARGable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable).

For another [week mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week) the expression must be adjusted.

Answer (score 0):

We can use the [`WEEK()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week) function here:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(user_id)
FROM users
WHERE WEEK(registration_date) >= WEEK(NOW()) AND
      YEAR(registration_date) >= YEAR(NOW());
```